# What is meant by "Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server"

Tags: sql-server, terminology, instance

I am cloning a server to perform an in-place upgrade and I will have to change the name of that server - which has a SQL Server with just one instance (default instance) installed on it.

I am reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and it keeps referring to "stand alone" instance" of SQL Server. What is meant by *stand alone* here?

Answer (score 2):

Stand Alone:

> Operating, functioning, or existing without additions or assistance; independent; able to be separate or separated.

And that's precisely what is referring to on that article, to a self-sustained SQL Server instance, not participating (as Aaron commented) on a Failover Cluster or a WSFC. That's why the article refers to some scenarios where renaming there computer is directly forbidden or it could wreak havoc as it's not a "stand alone" but part or some other process.